# Is having both static and non-static methods in one class considered bad practise?

Tags: javascript, static-methods

What I mean:
When in one javascript class I have some methods that don't use >this<, they are only called by instance "public" methods .
does it mean I need to put those method into a different class?

Example:

```
function TemplateRenderer(vars) {
    var a = this.transform_vars(vars); // doesn't use any instance vars
    this.b = this.even_further_transform(a);
}
TemplateRenderer.prorotype.render(tpl) {uses this.b}
```

The question is - should I place trnasform_vars outside the class?

Comment: There are many ways to write the exact same thing in javascript and, usually, it's just matter of preferences. Can you please provide us a pratical example to give you the proper answer to your question?

Comment: @briosheje done, hope it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> should I place `transform_vars` outside the class?

No. `transform_vars` seems to be very closely related to your `TemplateRenderer` class. So unless you find yourself need to transform vars everywhere else (so that an extra utility object could be justified), you should put it inside your class structure.

> they are only called by instance "public" methods

You could still make these methods private to your class, i.e. place everything in an IEFE. You might not want to expose them.

> methods that don't use `this`

are static, yes. While it doesn't really matter where exactly in your class you place them, it's standard practise in javascript to put them on the constructor function object. That way, they can be called without having constructed any instance (on which them were accessed if placed on the `.prototype`).

So you might do

```
function TemplateRenderer(vars) {
    var a = TemplateRenderer.transform_vars(vars);
    …
}
TemplateRenderer.transform_vars = function(vars) {
    … // doesn't use any instance vars
};
```